# CouchDB View with 2 Keys

Tags: dictionary, view, couchdb, mapreduce

I am looking for a general solution to a problem with couchdb views.

For example, have a view result like this:

```
{"total_rows":4,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"1","key":["imported","1"],"value":null},
{"id":"2","key":["imported","2"],"value":null},
{"id":"3","key":["imported","3"],"value":null},
{"id":"4","key":["mapped","4"],"value":null},
{"id":"5,"key":["mapped","5"],"value":null}
]
```

1) If I want to select only "imported" documents I would use this:

```
view?startkey=["imported"]&endkey=["imported",{}]
```

2) If I want to select all imported documents with an higher id then 2:

```
view?startkey=["imported",2]&endkey=["imported",{}]
```

3) If I want to select all imported documents  with an id between 2 and 4:

```
view?startkey=["imported",2]&endkey=["imported",4]
```

My Questtion is: How can I select all Rows with an id between 2 and 4?

Comment: Any reason you can't have a separate view that only emits the 2nd param?

Comment: The only reason is, that I have a lot of cases with the same problem and I want to avoid to "dublicate" all these views... I need this for scrolling functions..

Answer (score 2):

You can try to extend the solution above, but prepend keys with a kind of "emit index" flag like this:

```
map: function (doc) {
  emit ([0, doc.number, doc.category]); // direct order
  emit ([1, doc.category, doc.number]); // reverse order
}
```

so you will be able to request them with

```
view?startkey=[0, 2]&endkey=[0, 4, {}]
```

or

```
view?startkey=[1, 'imported', 2]&endkey=[1, 'imported', 4]
```

But 2 different views will be better anyway.

Comment: Ok, I think there is no solution other then creating two seperate views

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem a little while ago so I'll explain my solution. Inside of any map function you can have multiple `emit()` calls. A map function in your case might look like:

```
function(doc) {
  emit([doc.number, doc.category], null);
  emit([doc.category, doc.number], null);
}
```

You can also use `?include_docs=true` to get the documents back from any of your queries. Then your query to get back rows 2 to 4 would be

```
view?startkey=[2]&endkey=[4,{}]
```

You can view the rules for sorting at [CouchDB View Collation](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
But this solution is even worser then to make two views, because in this solution, you don't know if a result row is an [number,category] or [category,number] element. I mean you dont know, if the first key element is a category or a number (if for example both are strings).

Comment: @leftjustified: Is there a reason that the number in the key has to be a string?

Comment: number / category is only one example, you could also call it groupName and categoryName or something other... or city and category..